# Error: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will email out an HTML table that uses a query with Unions in it. But I keep getting:

"All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists."

I went through and I believe all my selects for the Unions have the same number for columns. Any one have any ideas? I am using SQL 2012.

```
DECLARE @DailySales varchar(max)

With Daily_Sales_CTE as (
SELECT 
TD = 'Base','',
TD = CONVERT(int,SUM(totalprice)/1000),'', 
TD = CONVERT(int,SUM(totalcost)/1000),'',
TD = CONVERT(int,SUM(totalprice-totalcost)/1000),'',
TD = CONVERT(decimal (3,3),1-((SUM(totalcost))/(SUM(totalprice)))),'',
TD = CONVERT(int, SUM(totweight)/2000)
FROM ubs_saleslookup_cost A
WHERE DATEPART(MM,A.date) = DATEPART(MM, GETDATE()) AND DATEPART(YYYY,A.date) =          DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()) and DATEPART(DD,A.date) = DATEPART(DD, GETDATE()) and
a.cust<>'1522292' and a.cust<>'1435230' and a.location<>'g-ds'
union
Select
TD = 'Direct','',
TD = CONVERT(int,SUM(totalprice)/1000),'', 
TD = CONVERT(int,SUM(totalcost)/1000),'',
TD = CONVERT(int,SUM(totalprice-totalcost)/1000),'',
TD = CONVERT(decimal (3,3),1-((SUM(totalcost))/(SUM(totalprice)))),'',
TD = CONVERT(int, SUM(totweight)/2000)
FROM ubs_saleslookup_cost A
WHERE DATEPART(MM,A.date) = DATEPART(MM, GETDATE()) AND DATEPART(YYYY,A.date) = DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()) and DATEPART(DD,A.date) = DATEPART(DD, GETDATE()) and
a.cust<>'1522292' and a.cust<>'1435230' and a.location='g-ds'
union
SELECT 
TD = 'Acero',
TD = CONVERT(int,SUM(totalprice)/b.xchgrate/1000),'', 
TD = CONVERT(int,SUM(totalcost)/b.xchgrate/1000),'',
TD = CONVERT(int,SUM(totalprice-totalcost)/b.xchgrate/1000),'',
TD = CONVERT(decimal (3,3),1-((SUM(totalcost)/b.xchgrate)/(SUM(totalprice)/b.xchgrate))),'',
TD = CONVERT(int, SUM(totweight)/2000)
FROM acero.dbo.ubs_saleslookup_cost A
left join acero.dbo.acero_rate b on DATEPART(YYYY,A.date)=b.year1 and DATEPART(MM,A.date)=b.periodid
WHERE DATEPART(MM,A.date) = DATEPART(MM, GETDATE()) AND DATEPART(YYYY,A.date) = DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE())  and   DATEPART(DD,A.date) = DATEPART(DD, GETDATE()) and
a.cust<>'1512098'
group by b.xchgrate
union
SELECT
TD = 'Chile','',
TD = CONVERT(int,SUM(totalprice)/b.xchgrate/1000),'', 
TD = CONVERT(int,SUM(totalcost)/b.xchgrate/1000),'',
TD = CONVERT(int,SUM(totalprice-totalcost)/b.xchgrate/1000),'',
TD = CONVERT(decimal (3,3),1-((SUM(totalcost)/b.xchgrate)/(SUM(totalprice)/b.xchgrate))),'',
TD = CONVERT(int, SUM(totweight)/2000)
FROM chile.dbo.ubs_saleslookup_cost A
left join chile.dbo.chile_rate b on DATEPART(YYYY,A.date)=b.year1 and DATEPART(MM,A.date)=b.periodid
WHERE DATEPART(MM,A.date) = DATEPART(MM, GETDATE()) AND DATEPART(YYYY,A.date) = DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE())  and   DATEPART(DD,A.date) = DATEPART(DD, GETDATE()) and
a.cust<>'1512098'
group by b.xchgrate
union
SELECT 
TD = 'Total','',
TD = CONVERT(int,SUM(a.totalprice+b.totalprice+isnull(c.totalprice,0))/1000),'', 
TD = CONVERT(int,SUM(a.totalcost+b.totalcost+isnull(c.totalprice,0))/1000),'',
TD = CONVERT(int,SUM(a.totalprice-a.totalcost+b.totalprice-b.totalcost+isnull(c.totalprice-c.totalcost,0))/1000),'',
TD = CONVERT(decimal (3,3),1-((SUM(a.totalcost+b.totalcost+isnull(c.totalcost,0)))/(SUM(a.totalprice+b.totalprice+isnull(c.totalprice,0))))),'',
TD = CONVERT(int, SUM(a.totweight+b.totweight+isnull(c.totweight,0)))
FROM (select 'CurMonth' as Month, sum(totalprice) as totalprice, sum(totalcost) as totalcost, sum(totweight)/2000 as totweight
from ubs_saleslookup_cost 
WHERE DATEPART(MM,date) = DATEPART(MM, GETDATE()) AND DATEPART(YYYY,date) = DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()) and   DATEPART(DD,date) = DATEPART(DD, GETDATE()) and
cust<>'1522292' and cust<>'1435230') a
left join (select 'CurMonth' as Month, sum(a.totalprice)/b.xchgrate as totalprice, sum(a.totalcost)/b.xchgrate as totalcost, 
sum(a.totweight)/2000 as totweight
from acero.dbo.ubs_saleslookup_cost A
left join acero.dbo.acero_rate b on DATEPART(YYYY,A.date)=b.year1 and DATEPART(MM,A.date)=b.periodid
WHERE DATEPART(MM,A.date) = DATEPART(MM, GETDATE()) AND DATEPART(YYYY,A.date) = DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE())  and   DATEPART(DD,A.date) = DATEPART(DD, GETDATE()) and
a.cust<>'1512098' group by b.xchgrate) b on a.month=b.month
left join (select 'CurMonth' as Month, sum(a.totalprice)/b.xchgrate as totalprice, sum(a.totalcost)/b.xchgrate as totalcost, 
sum(a.totweight)/2000 as totweight
from chile.dbo.ubs_saleslookup_cost A
left join chile.dbo.chile_rate b on DATEPART(YYYY,A.date)=b.year1 and DATEPART(MM,A.date)=b.periodid
WHERE DATEPART(MM,A.date) = DATEPART(MM, GETDATE()) AND DATEPART(YYYY,A.date) = DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE())  and   DATEPART(DD,A.date) = DATEPART(DD, GETDATE()) and
a.cust<>'1512098' group by b.xchgrate) c on a.month=c.month

)

Select @DailySales = 
N'<style type="text/css">
#box-table
{
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-top: 7px solid #9baff1;
border-bottom: 7px solid #9baff1;
}
#box-table th
{
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: Bold;
background: #b9c9fe;
border-right: 2px solid #9baff1;
border-left: 2px solid #9baff1;
border-bottom: 2px solid #9baff1;
color: #039;
}
#box-table td
{
border-right: 1px solid #aabcfe;
border-left: 1px solid #aabcfe;
border-bottom: 1px solid #aabcfe;
color: #669;
}
tr:nth-child(odd)    { background-color:#eee; }
tr:nth-child(even)   { background-color:#fff; } 
</style>'+  
N'<H1><font color="Black">MTD Results</H1>'+
N'<table id="box-table">'+
N'<tr><font color = "Black">
<th> Type </th>
<th> Sales </th>
<th> Cost </th>
<th> Margin </th>
<th> Percentage </th>
<th> Tons </th>
</tr>'
+ CAST ( ( select * from Daily_Sales_CTE

FOR XML PATH ('tr')
) as varchar(max))
+ '</table>'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@recipients = 'Email@domain.com',
@copy_recipients = '', 
@subject = 'Daily Sales',
@body = @DailySales,
@body_format = 'html'
```

Comment: select 'Acero','' I think. Hard to tell in that lot.

Comment: Well basically I am trying to create a HTML Table for an email. The query used to do this has Unions. With his code above I tired using CTE. Is that wrong? Or is there a better way? This is a bit above my head with SQL.

Comment: Baby steps will get you there.  Comment out all fields in your select clauses except the first one.  Run the query.  If it runs successfully, add the other fields one by one and run the query each time.  Eventually you will find the problem.  Make sure you treat those empty strings as fields as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one less column in the 'Acero' part (as Tony commented). Should be:

```
SELECT 
TD = 'Acero', '',
TD = CONVERT(int,SUM(totalprice)/b.xchgrate/1000),'',
```

However, when you fix this, you'll face another problem: all the columns in CTE must have a column name, and when you fix even that, you'll have the error that they are all called the same, and it's not allowed.

Comment: I took the TD's out and fixed that extra column. Thank you.