# Issue in union operation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query in database like

```
  SELECT 0 AS [DocumentType],'Select Document Type' [DocumentTypeX],0 ,0
  UNION
  SELECT dbo.tbDocumentType.*
  FROM dbo.tbDocumentType where Site=@Site
```

It throws error message "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists."

Comment: It seems your selected no of column not match in both statement

Comment: The error is as clear as it gets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345506/error-all-queries-combined-using-a-union-intersect-or-except-operator-must-hav)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
SELECT dbo.tbDocumentType.*
```

Select the columns matching your `UNION` fields

```
SELECT dbo.tbDocumentType.[DocumentType],
       dbo.tbDocumentType.[DocumentTypeX],
       dbo.tbDocumentType.[Something1],
       null  -- Or use any value you want if doesnt have the column
```

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost rule for UNION Operation:

```
 1.Both Query should have the same number of the resultset.
 2.Respective Columns of both queries should have similar data types.
 3.Never go with TableName.*.Instead Specify Column Names
```

Please check on that....